# R - Appending column to data frame. Match by year.

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

New to R.
Brain size of pea.

Suppose I have two separate data frames.

```
df1 = tibble(
  date = as.Date(c("1990-10-01", "1991-11-01", "1992-11-01")),
  wage = c(4, 5, 6) 
)

df2 = tibble(
  date = as.Date(c("1990-01-01", "1991-01-01", "1992-01-01")),
  cpi = c(2, 3, 4) 
)
```

I wish to add a column from the second data frame to the first. 
Also, I wish to match just the year of the date.

I'm thinking left_join factors in some how, but I am unsure as to exactly how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dplyr should work for this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1$year<-year(df1$date)
df2$year<-year(df2$date)
df1<-left_join(df1,df2[c('year','cpi')],by='year')
```

Comment: Thank-you @AffableAmbler

Comment: No problem. If you found these answers helpful, you can reward me and @Jordi with an upvote and/or accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
# turn dates into years
df1$date <- format(df1$date, "%Y")
df2$date <- format(df2$date, "%Y")
```

Use `base::merge` or `dplyr::lef_join` to combine the two:

```
merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)
# or
left_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: @ixodid Glad it helps. Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) whichever of the answers you prefer.